# How can i display the pythoon scipt data within flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, flask, flask-restful

one: A.ipynb
def factorial(n):
if n == 0:
return 1
else:
return n * factorial(n-1)

i want when i click on the button the result will be appear in the application.

flask application

````
from A import factorial 
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello(): 
    #return factorial(5)
    return "Hello"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()```

how can i solve it
````

Comment: I don't get your question?
Do you want to display 
one: A.ipynb def factorial(n): if n == 0: return 1 else: return n * factorial(n-1)

this code into HTML format on page or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use str to return number data.

return str(factorial (5))

Comment: can you please explain why we are used str so that i will take care next time